# How to access video files from sd card folder in android app

Tags: android, listview, sd-card

I am trying to display video files in listview from folder created in sdcard. I am using content provider such as:

```
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null);
```

But it reads all video files stored in sdcard. I want to access only files stored in folder in sdcard. I have also used:

```
Uri a = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfolder");
videocursor = managedQuery(a,proj, null, null, null);
```

But it gives error. Is there any way to include path of folder in managedQuery() or any other way to display video files from folder in listview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 String[] fileList;
    File videoFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfolder");

    if(videoFiles.isDirectory())
    {
        fileList=videoFiles.list();
    }

   for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
   {
       Log.e("Video:"+i+" File name",fileList[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to get file from resources then put in Uri.fromFile() :

```
 private boolean saveAs(int resource) { // save your file in sd card
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String fileName = "your_file.png";
        InputStream input = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        String path = root.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream save;
        byte[] buffer = null;
        int size = 0;
        try {
            size = input.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File deleteFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
            if (deleteFile.exists()) {
                deleteFile.delete();
            }
            save = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + fileName);
            save.write(buffer);
            save.flush();
            save.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

    Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                "your_file.png")) // get it from Uri
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use managedquerry as below to get the videos from a specified folder on sd-card....

```
videoCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    videoProjection, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    new String[]{"%M-Videos%"}, null);
```